# Magento Template path hints show for everybody

Tags: php, magento

I'm developing in a magento shop and enabled the template path hints, to see in which file I have to work. I entered my IP address at the top so only I would be able to see the hints. But after 10 minutes I received a phone call from a customer who told me the website showed a lot of errors.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please check if ip setting is overwritten on store view scope.

Comment: Did you make sure to set the hint templating visible only to the ip addresses? (I believe you need to check something to make it not global).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unforunately it isn't. I set the template path hints on the highest store level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the scope to store level and insert your ip address.

Comment: Much like what Gerard said. But this did it for me! Thanks!